# How to find the maximum directional derivative at a point p

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I am given the following function $$F(x,y,z)=x^2y+y^2-z^4$$ and point $(2,1,1)$ and I am asked to find the max directional derivative at the point

Here is my attempt to solve it:
$$F_x=2xy, F_y =x^2+2y, F_z=-4z^3$$
Therefore 
$$\nabla f(x,y,z)\mid_{2,1,1}= 4i+6j-4k \text{ and the unit vector } a = 1/2 i+4/3j-1/2k$$ 
Hence the maximum value of $\nabla_v f$ is given by 
$$4/2+18/4-4/2= 9/2$$
Can anyone confirm that all my steps are correct and my solution is correct to if not please show me the right solution

Comment: How did you come up with $a$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The directional derivative in the direction of the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$ is
$$\nabla{F}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{d}}= |\nabla{F}||\hat{\mathbf{d}}|\cos(\theta)$$

Since $|\hat{\mathbf{d}}|=1$ and the maximum value of $\cos(\theta)=1$ (achieved when $\theta =0$ and $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$ points in the same direction as the gradient) 
the maximum directional derivative is in the direction of $\nabla{F}$ and has value $|\nabla{F}|$. Only the gradient of $F$ is required, $\hat{\mathbf{a}}$ does not come in to it.

Comment: Would you explain how you got d to be 1 if you didn't compute unit vector ? I mean the formula said $|a||∇f|cos(θ)$ where $cos(θ) =1$ you get $|a||∇f| $ where a is the unit vector right

Comment: The directional derivative as mentioned above will attain its maximum if $\theta=0^\circ$

Comment: @Reddevil magnitude of vector d-hat is 1 because it is a unit vector.

Comment: This is a very elegant proof, thanks!