# Given $f\colon\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f'(A,(a,b))=ab+3b+4a$ find maximum derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Given $f\colon\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $$f'(A,(a,b))=ab+3b+4a$$ find the value of maximum derivative at point $A$, knowing that $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$.

---

We observe that $$f'(A,(1,0))=f_x(A)=4,\qquad f'(A,(0,1))=f_y(A)=3,$$ so as $f\in\mathcal{C}^1$ we observe that $$\vec{\nabla}f(A)=(f_x(A),f_y(A))=(4,3).$$ We need to find $f'_{\max}(A)$, so $$f'_{\max}(A)=\lVert\vec{\nabla}f(A)\rVert=\sqrt{4^2+3^2}=5.$$ Is it correct?

P.S. Some of you asked what does $f(A,(a,b))$ mean. I suspect that this notation refers to [Directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) of $f$ at point $A$ in direction $\vec{v}=(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Apparently, and a fortiori by definition, $\;A\;$ is a point in the plane, but then...how do we know $\;f'_x(A)=4\;$ , for example? And what do you call $\;f\;$ to? The function's gradient (which cannot be as it is given as a scalar)...or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio $f'_x(A)=(1)(0)+3(0)+4(1)=4$.

Comment: $f'(A)$ is by definition a linear operator, and it's impossible that $f'(A,(a,b)) = ab + 3b + 4a$.

Comment: @Mmanoo I really don't understand what you're doing ,sorry. In particular, I don't understand what $\;f'\;$ means for a scalar function in two variables...

Comment: @AdamLatosiński Ok, so then it seems to be *the differential* of $\;f\;$ ...right? But, as you say, it can't be as it is given as a scalar...pretty confusing all this.

Comment: The statement is just as I indicated, I didn't change anything. I think that the derivative must return a number, and $ab+3b+4a$ is a number, since $a,b\in\Bbb{R}$ and $\vec{v}=(a,b)\in\Bbb{R}^2$, isn't it?

Comment: See [Directional derivative (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

Comment: Ah, I see, if it's a directional derivative then it's possible. I was confused by notation, $f'(A)$ denotes a Frechet derivaitive for me.

Comment: Ok, so **then** ....it seems to be $\;f'\;$ is the notation the OP uses of *directional derivative* ...and then $\;F'(A,(1,0)\;$ is, I am guessing now, the directional derivative of $\;f\;$ at $\;A\;$ in the direction $\;(1,0)\;$  ...or something like this. It is wise to explain one's symbols.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(A,(a,b))$? It seems that both $A$ and $(a,b)$ are supposed to be points of $\Bbb R,$ based on the fact that $\Bbb R^2$ is the domain of $f,$ but I suspect that this is not supposed to be the case. Please adjust your post to clarify what you mean.

Comment: And if my guess (and apparently Adam's as well) is correct, then yes: the answer the op gives seems to be correct.

Comment: Ok, then please explain now what do you mean by "maximum derivative"? What kind of derivative you're talking about here?

Comment: @AdamLatosiński If our (or my) guess is correct, the OP surely mean in what direction is the rate of change maximal, and we know that it is in the direction of the gradient, so that's why it appears there...:0

Comment: @AdamLatosiński you can check this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2201127/525384.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Do you want to post an answer?

Comment: The method works in the question that you linked, but won't work here because here the directional derivative is nonlinear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to go against the grain and say **no** for the following pedantic reason: there does not exist a $C^1$ function $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ and a point $A\in\mathbb R^2$ satisfying
$$
f'(A,(a,b))=ab+3b+4a,\qquad \forall (a,b)\in\mathbb R^2.
$$
Indeed, this follows from the observation that
$$
f'(A,(a,b))=af_x(A)+bf_y(A),
$$
so there is no opportunity for an $ab$ term to enter.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen in an oportunity that $f'(A,(a,b))=af_x(A)+bf_y(A)$, but why does the derivative need to have that form? Why do we need the derivative to be linear?

Comment: @manooooh If a function is $\mathcal C^1$, then its directional derivative has to be linear.

Comment: @manooooh It follows directly from the definition of the directional derivative that it is linear - and it will sort out some confusion if you include the definition of the (nonstandard) notation $f'(A,(a,b))$ in the question itself. Note I am not saying that the derivative varies linearly as a function of $A$: instead, I am saying that for a fixed $A$, the directional derivative at the point $A$ is a linear operator.

Answer (score 2):

As pre-kidney noted, a function with such directional derivative won't be $\mathcal C^1$. You can still try to solve the problem though.

If by $f_{\rm max}'(A)$ you mean $$f_{\rm max}'(A) = \sup_{v\in\mathbb R^2} \frac{|f'(A,v)|}{||v||} $$
then your method is not correct. The method works in the question that you linked in the comments, but won't work here because here the directional derivative is nonlinear.

You have
\begin{align}\sup_{v\in\mathbb R^2} \frac{|f'(A,v)|}{||v||} &= \sup_{v\in\mathbb R^2,||v||=1} |f'(A,v)| = \sup_{(a,b): a^2+b^2=1} |f'(A,(a,b))| = \\ &= \sup_{(a,b): a^2+b^2=1} |ab+4a+3b|\end{align}
Using the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), you can reduce the problem of finding the supremum to solving the system of equations:
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l} b + 4 + 2\lambda a = 0 \\ a + 3 + 2\lambda b = 0 \\ a^2+b^2 =1 \end{array}\right. $$
This unfortunately gives you
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{l} a = \frac{-8\lambda +3}{4\lambda^2-1} \\ b = \frac{-6\lambda +4}{4\lambda^2-1} \\ (-6\lambda +4)^2 + (-8\lambda +3)^2 =(4\lambda^2-1)^2 \end{array}\right. $$
And that last equation doesn't seem to have exact solutions, you can only solve it numerically.